# Post IP and Location from Javascript File to PHP page

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to simply collect a user's IP and location from the form after it is filled in.

**This is the content of my javascript file using freegeoip:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.getJSON("http://freegeoip.net/json/", function(data) {
    var country_code = data.country_code;
    var country = data.country_name;
    var ip = data.ip;
    var time_zone = data.time_zone;
    var latitude = data.latitude;
    var longitude = data.longitude;
});

$.get("http://freegeoip.net/json/", function (response) {
    $("#ip").html("IP: " + response.ip);
    $("#address").html("Location: " + response.city);
}, "jsonp");
});
```

**This is the content of my html form**

```
<form id="test" method="POST" name ="Login" action="post_ipadd.php">
<input name = "ip" id="ip" type="hidden" value=""></input>  
<input name = "address" id="address" type="hidden" value=""></input>
</form>
```

**This is the content of my php**

```
$IP= $_POST['ip']; 
 $Address = $_POST['address'];
```

**Then to retrieve it:**

```
$email_message .= "IP Address: ".$IP. "\n";
$email_message .= "Location: ".$Address. "\n";
```

However, I can see the correct ip address and location if I set the input fields in the form to divs with the same names/ids. But I am struggling to post these values from the javascript to my PHP page.

Comment: You don't know how to submit form? Either `<button type="submit">Submit</button>` or use Ajax for that.

Comment: I don't use `jQuery` but shouldn't `$("#ip").html("IP: " + response.ip);` be more like `$("#ip").value("IP: " + response.ip);`??

Comment: For getting their IP address just use `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` in your code that handles the form being submitted. There's no reason to use JavaScript for this.

Comment: @Justinas I have a submit button. The IP and Location just don't Post to the PHP page

Comment: @DiddleDot I need both the IP addres and Locaton, Hence the use of Javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `.val()` to set an inputs value with jquery.

Also, the two requests are unnecessary:

```
$(function(){

    $.get("http://freegeoip.net/json/", function(data) {

        $("#ip").val(data.ip);
        $("#address").val(data.city);

    });

};
```

Comment: I tried with just this request, still not working. This is what I see in my error log: [03-May-2017 11:26:09 Etc/GMT] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: address in /home/intlra87/public_html/vaf/post_ipadd.php on line 45
[03-May-2017 11:27:19 Etc/GMT] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: address in /home/intlra87/public_html/vaf/post_ipadd.php on line 45

Comment: What do you see?

Comment: The value is stil not being stored in the hidden input field

Comment: How are you submitting the form?

Comment: I'm using a regular submit button. I tested it, with user input in a regular text input field, the data is posted, but as for the IP and Location in the hidden field, no luck

Comment: Hard to help without seeing the live page. As a start, change the inputs type to text so you can see the values. Are they added by the javascript?

Comment: I post it like this: $IP = $_POST['ip'];   AND Then I call the variable again to be sent via email like this: $email_message .= "IP Address: ".$IP. "\n";

Comment: Oh I just changed the input type to text, the values are actually not being added by the javascript

Comment: any errors in the javascript console? Did you try adding `console.log(data);` to check the reponse from the ajax call?

Comment: I'm not so good at javascript, I don't know how to debug the javascript console

Comment: Ok, I went back to my previous script, with the two requests and now it works fine.  But once the input type is hidden then it does not Post the Values

Answer (score 0):

First you need to fix your inputs to be valid html.

```
<input name="ip" id="ip" type="hidden" value=""/>  
<input name="address" id="address" type="hidden" value=""/>
```

Then you need to fix your JavaScript to alter the value of the input's `value` attribute like this -

```
$.get("http://freegeoip.net/json/", function (response) {
    $("#ip").val(response.ip);
    $("#address").val(response.city);
}, "jsonp");
```

Now when you submit the form `$_POST['ip']` and `$_POST['address']` should get the values you want.

Comment: This is what I see in my error log: [03-May-2017 11:26:09 Etc/GMT] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: address in /home/intlra87/public_html/vaf/post_ipadd.php on line 45
[03-May-2017 11:27:19 Etc/GMT] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: address in /home/intlra87/public_html/vaf/post_ipadd.php on line 45